# Why in a Page Object class we return the own class in which methods?

Tags: selenium, junit, cucumber, pageobjects

Why we return the own page in which method?
For example:

```
public class Page{
       public Page testElement(){
          #code
       return this;
    }
```

Why do i do that? Can i return other pages, if I, why can i?

Comment: Yes you can return other pages. It's a design approach to allow method chaining and provide a more guided method to test creation. If there is a return it allows you you to create more fluent-like statements. For example if there is a return on the method you can do 1 liners such as: login.Setusername("hello").SetPassword("world").ClickLogin().DoSoemthingOnHomePage();  - you do less object creation yourself.

Comment: @RichEdwards you could write that as an answer, not just comment

Comment: @Prophet - fair point.  It was only designed to be a quick response - I wasn't intending on the detila....but I suppose it is actually an answer.  Ta mate.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can call them after, something like `installProcess.installProcessAndConnectTo().       mainScreen.clickOnPhoneIcon.dialer.openAPPSettings();`

Answer (score 1):

As covered in the comments + with a bit more detail.

Yes you can return other pages.

Returning a Page class is a design approach to allow method chaining and provide a more guided approach to test creation.

For this approach you want to the return the page you expect to be after your action. For example, after you click Login you're expect to be on the home page - so return that page.

If there is a return it allows you you to create more fluent-like statements and use inteli-sense to aid your creation.

For example if there is a return on the method you can do 1 liners such as:

```
login.SetUsername("hello").SetPassword("world").ClickLogin().DoSoemthingOnHomePage();
```

That's compared to the normal long form:

```
var login = new login(driver);
login.SetUsername("hello");
login.SetPassword("world");
login.ClickLogin();

var home = new Home(driver);
home.DoSoemthingOnHomePage();
```

Comment: huum, but if i want that my method return a String, can i too? Is it usual?

Comment: Or for example, i have a element that depending what i select, i will to a differents pages, what is the best thing to do?

Comment: @Noelen you don't have to do use it - it adds complication and muddies the water. If you have an application that's complicated and doesn't support a method-chaining approach then don't use it. If you want to return a string then return a string. If you want to return multiple values then google "return tuple" for more research.  If you have a single element where interaction with it branches into multiple different locations then control it with test data where so you know your expected page for each test individually